# Make a Text Field the same size as the font size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I was wondering if there is a way to make a Text Field the same size as the font used for the text inside of it.

One of the options that I've tried was:

```
mytextfield.height = mytextfield.textHeight
```

But it didn't do the job, because textHeight is actually the height of the highest letter in the text, so that is not something you can rely on.

I've also tried using getTextFormat().size:

```
mytextfield.height = mytextfield.getTextFormat().size
```

But it returned:

```
error 1118 Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possible unrelated type Number.
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the textfield as high as the highest letter? Try mytextfield.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT; - I believe the height should be resized automatically as well.

Comment: @Philarmon is correct, vertical size is adjusted with this method. I think the OPs point is that if the text were lower case "eee" the field would be too short to then show "EEE".